# Merge pandas dataframes only where an element appears on the same position

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
userID  |  value1

7           33
2           11
1           22
6           67
7           77
6           76
2           87
```

and

```
userID  |  value2

7           12
2           14
3           64
6           15
5           23
4           56
2           35
```

I want to merge the two dataframes on UserID only where the same user ID appears at the same index, so the result would be:

```
userID  |  value1  | value2

7           33        12
2           11        14
6           67        15
2           87        35
```

Because `userIDs` 7, 2, 6, 2 appear on the same positions (same row number) in both dataframes. Is this possible in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another solution using `pd.merge`:

```
df1.set_index('userID', append=True).merge(df2.set_index('userID', append=True), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
          value1  value2
  userID                
0 7           33      12
1 2           11      14
3 6           67      15
6 2           87      35
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

```
s = df1['userID'] == df2['userID']

df = df1[s].copy()
df['value2'] = df2.loc[s, 'value2'].values
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
s=df1.userID.eq(df2.userID)
df=df1.loc[s].assign(value2=df2.value2).copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

append user id as index, and join on the indices

```
res = (df1
       .set_index('userID',append=True)
       .join(df2.set_index('userID',append=True), how='inner')
      )

res

          value1    value2
 userID     
0   7        33     12
1   2        11     14
3   6        67     15
6   2        87     35
```

Comment: Nice approach ~